# selenium, Cannot get the text of a message

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying get a message text to check on it

[image]

So I got it with the selector and make a function to return the text on it with .text; method, but when I was debugging, I realized that the text always like this "" so the assertion didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

to get text of the element, try:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('your_xpath')
element.get_attribute('value')
```

or could you attach how element lookes in DOM?

Comment: sure here is the element looks like :                                                                              <div class="alert alert-danger alert-InvalidValidation" style="display: none;">
                            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                            Invalid Username or Password
                        </div>

Comment: and here is my function to return the text                                                                  
  public string GetwrongDataMessage()
        {
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
            wrongEnteredDataMessage = wait.Until((d) =>d.FindElement(By.CssSelector(("#kt_login_form > div:nth-child(1)"))));
            string x = wrongEnteredDataMessage.Text;
            return wrongEnteredDataMessage.Text;
        }

Comment: @mohamedmostafa you need to find by class 'alert alert-danger alert-InvalidValidation', something like this `//div[@class='alert alert-danger alert-InvalidValidation']

Comment: I tried it , but I got the same result " the text is always empty"

Comment: @mohamedmostafa seems like you're using java, right?
String word = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-danger alert-InvalidValidation']")).getText();
System.out.println(word);

Comment: no um using C# , so the method called .text , And Unfortunately i got the same result the returned text is empty

Comment: @mohamedmostafa it text in Capidatal, like that: driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-danger alert-InvalidValidation']")).Text;

Comment: yes , I tried this also but same result . I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

try this to check if exists

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Invalid Username or Password')]")
```

or try this to get text from some element

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('your_span_xpath').getText()
```